# Why privacy ipv6 address cannot connect the internet in guest vm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ipv6

I have a guest ubuntu 14.04 installed in kvm, host is a fedora 20.
The eth1 nic of guest is in macvtap bridge mode. Ubuntu default enables ipv6 privacy extension, and prefers the temporary address:

```
$ ip -6 addr show dev eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
inet6 2001:da8:207:e216:a935:a562:3102:7e00/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
   valid_lft 599380sec preferred_lft 80380sec
inet6 2001:da8:207:e216:5054:ff:fed5:8cae/64 scope global dynamic 
   valid_lft 2591548sec preferred_lft 604348sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed5:8cae/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
```

However, I cann't connect to the Internet by ipv6:

```
ping6 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(hkg03s10-in-x06.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3023ms
```

If I delete the temporary address `2001:da8:207:e216:a935:a562:3102:7e00/64` or set `net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr` to 1, it will work:

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth1.use_tempaddr=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.use_tempaddr = 1
# ifdown eth1                              
# ifup eth1
# ping6 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(hkg03s10-in-x06.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from hkg03s10-in-x06.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=305 ms
64 bytes from hkg03s10-in-x06.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=305 ms
```

And the host os (fedora 20) could access `ipv6.google.com` even if I set `net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr` to 2.

It seems to me that the privacy address in kvm guest cannot access the ipv6 Internet. Why is it?

Comment: First thing you need to check is: Can the guest ping the host? Can the host ping both temporary and static IP address of the guest?

Comment: Did you create the VM manually or with virt-manager or something else?

Comment: @kasperd the guest and the host are unreachable to each other, both the static and temporary IP, returns "destination unreachable" error. But It seems they are unreachable in nature. refer  http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Guest_can_reach_outside_network,_but_can't_reach_host_(macvtap)

Comment: @MichaelHampton by virt-manager, NIC type is macvtap, bridge mode

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It seems to be because in libvirt, the default setting of the `trustGuestRxFilters` attribute is `no`.

After setting `trustGuestRxFilters` to `yes` on the `interface` element in the guest's libvirt XML, the IPv6 privacy addresses in the guest are now working for me.